# validate captcha before submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation, captcha

I've use `captcha` for form registration, within that I have [**validation engine**](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/) for form inline validation.   I'm stuck in validating the *equity of `captcha`.*

```
<p class="veriText">
    <label>Enter the Verification Text </label> <span style="color:red;">*</span>
    <input class="validate[required] text-input" type="text" name="captcha" id="captcha" class="text" value="" />                   
</p>
<img src="<?= get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/captcha_code_file.php?rand=<?php echo rand();?>" id='captchaimg'><br/>
```

PHP validation: (works perfectly)

```
if(strcasecmp($_SESSION['code'], $_POST['captcha']) != 0){
  //----mismatch values
}
```

But the same thing in js I have tried like

```
var session = <?php echo $_SESSION['code'] ?>;  // this value is different 
                                                // from captcha image
```

Is it possible to validate captcha before submitting the form in Javascript/jQuery?

Comment: Correct me if im wrong, but a captcha is to non-botify the request, if your going to make multiple requests then surly the captcha can be bypassed or spoofed for the request as its not tied to a single request, even worse if your going to echo the code in the source. Validate the captcha with the other fields ect **server-side** if values are invalid use jquery to reload the captcha like you would any other input.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the line `var session = <?php echo $_SESSION['code'] ?>;` is in your html page.

When the page is generated your captcha image script is not invoked and thus `$_SESSION['code']` is not initialized. The value you are getting is the `code` from the previous request to `captcha_code_file.php`. Once your page is loaded (at-least the html part) and the browser decides to call `captcha_code_file.php` your captcha image gets invoked and a new `$_SESSION['code']` is created.

I don't recommend this, but if you want to get the current `$_SESSION['code']` try to use an Ajax request to retrieve the new `$_SESSION['code']` from another php file (don't call `captcha_code_file.php` or your session will be reset again.

**Note:** Never try to validate your captcha at user end. You are defeating the main purpose of captcha.

Answer (score 1):

Create one ajax request for checking capcha using JavaScript, example is provided below:

```
var postData = $("form").serialize();
var requestUrl = '/check_capcha.php';
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             dataType: "json",
             data: postData,
             url: requestUrl,
             success:function(data){
                // success or fail message

             }
         });
```

check_capcha.php contains:

```
if(strcasecmp($_SESSION['code'], $_POST['captcha']) != 0){
  //----mismatch values
echo 0;
}else{
echo 1;
}
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the javascript code before  (although session is same throughout the page).
Just try a dummy code in a plain file and check the session value
OR 
You can use $.ajax() to call PHP page for captcha validation

Answer (score 0):

html look like this

```
  $rand = mt_rand(100000,999999);
  <span class="captcha"><?php echo $rand; ?></span>
  <input name="captcha" type="text" id="captcha-compare" />
```

In javascript use something like that for validation engine

```
 $('#frm-register').submit(function() {
    if( $('#captcha-compare').val() != $('.captcha').text() ) {
        $('#captcha-compare').validationEngine('showPrompt', 'Invalid captcha', 'load');
        return false;
    }
 });
```

and in php first take $rand in session then submitting capture the input text captcha and session

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code to validate the captcha or you can also use AJAX code to validate the values before submitting the code.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var session = '<?php echo $_SESSION['code'] ?>';
    if(Form.captcha.value == session)
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      Form.submit();
    }
    </script>
```